# Find better way to handle pagination JSON with MVVM in Swift 5

Tags: swift, swiftui

currently my project uses structure **MVVM**. I have a Pagination JSON like this:

```
{
    "has_next": false,
    "next_params": {
        "limit": 10,
        "offset": 10
    },
    "results": [
        { "id": 1, "name": "A Place" },
        { "id": 2, "name": "A Night" }
    ]
}
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
class LifeStoryViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var lifes: [Life] = []
    var has_next: Bool = true
    var next_params: [String:Any] = [:]
    var fetching: Bool = false

    func fetchLifeStories () {
        let url = URL(string: STRINGURL)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, res, err) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let vvv = try! JSONDecoder().decode(LifeStories.self, from: data!)
                self.lifes = vvv.results
            }
        }.resume()
    }

}
```

As you guys see, I have a model LifeStories:

```
struct Life: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var thumbnail: String
}

struct LifeStories: Codable {
    var has_next: Bool
    var results: [Life]
}
```

Can I remove `LifeStories` model and handle it inside the `LifeStoryViewModel` instead? How can I do this because I think `LifeStories` model is not necessary.

Comment: The convention for var naming in swift is `camelCase`.

Comment: Isn't that what you are already doing in your view model?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Not Yet. I have problem about JSON Parsing

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Could you help me please

Comment: But that is not what your question is about? Please clarify what you are asking (by editing the question and not as comments)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I want to ask if I can remove `LifeStories` model and handle it in function `fetchLifeStories` instead?

Comment: Not when you are decoding your json but you can afterwards

Comment: On another note, you should add some proper error handling to your decoding rather than using `try!` and also verify `data` isn't nil

Comment: Why do you need to do that? can you tell please!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic type for paginated responses. Here's an example from the app I'm working on:

```
struct PaginatedResponse<Element: Codable>: Codable {
    var count: Int
    var next: String?
    var previous: String?
    var results: [Element]
}
```